# Custom view has subviews which don't update when I set their state

Tags: android

I have a custom view which has within it various subviews. If I change the font color for the subviews the change doesn't appear on screen.

The model looks like:

```
[customview]
   [button1 /] [button2 /] [button3 /] ...
[/customview]
```

with fontcolor black changing to fontcolor grey. Doesn't work whether I call invalidate or not:

```
int numChildren = getChildCount();

    if (numChildren > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
            if (getChildAt(i) instanceof Button) {
                Button l = (Button) getChildAt(i);
                l.setEnabled(false);
                l.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                l.invalidate();
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I get the change to "take" in the view? So far the only thing that works is removing all the childviews and then laboriously readding them with the new font color - but this is extremely slow and inefficient.

EDIT: I made sure that the change was being propogated using the following code:

```
if (getChildAt(i) instanceof Button) {
                Button l = (Button)getChildAt(i);
                l.setEnabled(false);
                Log.d("Log","State was " +String.valueOf(l.isEnabled()));
            }
```

And I receive log messages proving that the state of the buttons is changing, however the font color doesn't change. Here is the color xml that I use for the buttons:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:color="@color/gray" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:color="@color/black"/>
```

Comment: you should use a color selector

Comment: Are you doing it in UI (main) thread? Ideally, it should work if done in UI (main) thread.

Comment: @maveroid yes, I'm not using any threads to do this.
Blackbelt I need to do the change programmatically in response to various changes that the user might do in the UI - the buttons are already on a color selector, but since the "enabled" doesn't change either - it doesn't change color

Comment: Maybe your custom container isn't forwarding the invalidation properly.